# Pods can't mount disks on managed aks cluster

Tags: azure-aks, kubernetes-pvc

I tried simple PVC example from [here](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage) with nginx claiming azure-managed-disk and I getting 'unable to mount' error, see below. Also I can't remove the created PV with '*kubectl delete pv pvc-3f3c3c78-9779-11e9-a7eb-1aafd0e2f988*'.

```
$kubectl get events

LAST SEEN TYPE REASON KIND MESSAGE

10m Warning FailedMount Pod MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "pvc-3f3c3c78-9779-11e9-a7eb-1aafd0e2f988" : azureDisk - WaitForAttach failed within timeout node (aks-agentpool-10844952-2) diskId:(kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-3f3c3c78-9779-11e9-a7eb-1aafd0e2f988) lun:(1)

22s Warning FailedMount Pod Unable to mount volumes for pod "nginx_default(bd16b9c8-97b2-11e9-9018-eaa2ea1705c5)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"nginx". list of unmounted volumes=[volume]. list of unattached volumes=[volume default-token-92rj6]
```

My managed aks cluster is using v1.12.8 , SP has contributor role (owner role doesn't not help too). There is **storage class 'managed-premium'**, in the yaml from my simple nginx example (link provided).

Comment: share your storageclass\pvc?

Comment: The nginx example was using storageClassName: managed-premium

Comment: edit those into the question please

Comment: Can you give out more details? give the output of the commands `kubectl describe pvc` and `kubectl describe pv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, there are no more details to judge the exact reason. Just list the possible reason here.

1. It's just a simple error that it's failed when the API call to Azure. If so, you just need to delete them and recreate again.
2. The node that the pod run in already has too many Azure disks attached. If so, you need to schedule the pod run in another node which does not attach to many disks.
3. The Azure disk cannot be unmounted or detached from the old node. It means that the PV is in use and attach to another node. If so, you need to create another dynamic PV that does not in use for your pod.

You can check carefully again according to these reasons. In my opinion, the third reason is the most possible one. Of curse, it all dependents on the actual situation. For more details about the similar errors, see [How to Understand & Resolve “Warning Failed Attach Volume” and “Warning Failed Mount” Errors in Kubernetes on Azure](https://portworx.com/understand-resolve-warning-failed-attach-volume-warning-failed-mount-errors-kubernetes-azure/).